# Set lookup field value in infopath form on new Item(List Infopath form)

Tags: lookup-column, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have lookup field called **project stage**, on item created I'd like to set to its default value,(***project start***). Then this field can only be changed by the Workflow as the project moves to the next next stage. How can I set the default value for this lookup field? Currently I am setting it in `ItemAdding` event. This field will not be changed by user directly.

Is there another way of doing it without code in InfoPath2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://kenkumar.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-set-default-value-for.html details a 'no code' mechanism for setting default values of lookups in Infopath.

Given your requirement I'd say set that on your New Item Form and remove the field from your edit form.